# pthread_create does not work due to void pointer and integer conversion error

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads, void, void-pointers

How/why do you convert to/from a void pointer or int?

The following code wrongly generates compiler errors:

```
while(num_producers > 0) {
    pthread_t tid; // id of pthread (not used except to call pthread_create)
    pthread_attr_t attr; // pthread attributes (not used except to call pthread_create)
    pthread_attr_init(&attr); // default pthread attributes
    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, producer, num_producers);
    num_producers--;
}
```

The following errors appear (all on the pthread_create line):

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(int)' to 'void* (*)(void*)'
  error: initializing argument 3 of 'int pthread_create(_opaque_pthread)t**, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)'
  error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'void*'
  error: initializing argument 4 of 'int pthread_create(_opaque_pthread_t**, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)'
```

I want to create a pthread that runs (only) the function "producer" also contained in the same file as main.  Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `producer` the right way:

```
void * producer(void * p)
{
    intptr_t n = (intptr_t)(p);

    // ... use "n"

}
```

Then:

```
int n = 42;

int res = pthread_create(&tid, &attr, producer, (void*)(n));
```

Comment: i'm confused, what do I do if producer has an int parameter instead of a void pointer?  I need to pass an int to producer, I have no void pointers so not sure what I would pass it if i asked for void * p what would a pointer to void do anyhow?  is that not a pointer to nothing? (i.e. like how a void function returns nothing)

Comment: so n becomes my int, so the function needs no parameters, but the void pointer still doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Do i just type the void pointer part in and then ignore it elsewhere?

Comment: @user2209501: Rewrite the function. It *has* to be of type `void * (void *)`. `void *` is an integral type, so you can use it to store integers.

Comment: ok will redeclare as that type.  So I can store an int in a void?  confused - i thought the meaning of [void] was nothingness (i.e. a [void] function returns nothing, not an int).

Comment: is void different from void *?

Comment: that worked, but it now puts a 0x in front of my ints and makes them hex?

Comment: A `void*` is an untyped pointer. `void` is nothing--- such as returning nothing or having no arguments.